# Passing Elastic Beanstalk PHP App Environment Variables to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I creating a php application on Elastic Beanstalk with custom environment variables to hide api keys. One of the API calls api key to be in javascript (just easier with source documentation). However, eb's custom environment variables don't seem to be passing to javascript (they do in php). Does anyone know how to pass eb custom env variables to javascript?

Answer (score 4):

Someone else has already answered the question well, however I'm concerned that you are using environment variables for the express purpose of keeping the API keys secret and yet you want them to be embedded in javascript, which will have the consequence of exposing that which you were trying to keep secret.

Maybe you could be more clear about what you want to keep private and what you're ok exposing.

PS - The answer from Edward Samuel should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple PHP script to generate the environment variable in JavaScript, e.g:

**api_key.js.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
    echo 'var api_key = ' . getenv('YOUR_ENV_VAR');
```

Include that file into your HTML as JavaScript, e.g:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="api_key.js.php"></script>
    <script src="your_actual_script_that_use_api_key.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```